# Does wait() release all locks?

Tags: java, wait

I wrote this program to check if a thread_1 holding lock on two different objects: `LOCK_OBJECT` and `FULL` goes into waiting mode on `LOCK_OBJECT` using `FULL.wait()`. I didn't think the consumer would get the `LOCK_OBJECT` lock, but the print didn't. So is there anything you missed?

Why does the consumer get the `LOCK_OBJECT` lock based on the printed results?

This is my code:

```java
public class TestSync {

    private volatile Integer amount = 0;
    private final Object LOCK_OBJECT = new Object();
    private final Object FULL = new Object();

    public void doubleSync() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Producer  trying to get LOCK_OBJECT lock ");
        synchronized (LOCK_OBJECT) {
            System.out.println("Producer get LOCK_OBJECT lock ");
            Print.sleep(3000);
            while (amount >= 0) {
                synchronized (FULL) {
                    System.out.println("full！");
                    FULL.wait();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("continue~");
            amount++;
        }
    }

    public void simpleSync() {
        System.out.println("Consumer trying to get LOCK_OBJECT lock ");
        synchronized (LOCK_OBJECT) {
            System.out.println("Consumer get LOCK_OBJECT lock");
        }
        System.out.println("Consumer release LOCK_OBJECT lock");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1, new ThreadFactory() {
            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                int index = atomicInteger.incrementAndGet();
                System.out.println("create no " + index + " thread");
                Thread t = new Thread(r, "one Thread-" + index);
                return t;
            }
        });
        threadPool.execute(() -> {
            try {
                new TestSync().doubleSync();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        Print.sleep(1000);
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1, new ThreadFactory() {
            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                int index = atomicInteger.incrementAndGet();
                System.out.println("create no " + index + " thread");
                Thread t = new Thread(r, "two Thread-" + index);
                return t;
            }
        });
        executorService.execute(() -> {
            try {
                new TestSync().simpleSync();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is the print result:

```
create no 1 thread
sleep 1000
Producer  trying to get LOCK_OBJECT lock 
Producer get LOCK_OBJECT lock 
sleep 3000
create no 2 thread
Consumer trying to get LOCK_OBJECT lock 
Consumer get LOCK_OBJECT lock
Consumer release LOCK_OBJECT lock
full！
```

Comment: use single instance instead of `new TestSync()` in each thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question does not compile. What is `Print`? It appears twice in your code. Once in method `main`

```java
Print.sleep(1000);
```

In the below code, I simply created a class named `Print` and defined a static method `sleep`.

[Locks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) work on objects that are shared between threads. In your code you create a separate `TestSync` object for each thread. Hence no shared objects. Try creating one instance of `TestSync` and send it to both threads. Also, you don't need a separate `ExecutorService` for each thread. You can use a single `ExecutorService` to launch many threads. The below code demonstrates.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class TestSync {
    private volatile Integer amount = 0;
    private final Object LOCK_OBJECT = new Object();
    private final Object FULL = new Object();

    public void doubleSync() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Producer  trying to get LOCK_OBJECT lock ");
        synchronized (LOCK_OBJECT) {
            System.out.println("Producer get LOCK_OBJECT lock ");
            Print.sleep(3000);
            while (amount >= 0) {
                synchronized (FULL) {
                    System.out.println("full！");
                    FULL.wait();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("continue~");
            amount++;
        }
    }

    public void simpleSync() {
        System.out.println("Consumer trying to get LOCK_OBJECT lock ");
        synchronized (LOCK_OBJECT) {
            System.out.println("Consumer get LOCK_OBJECT lock");
        }
        System.out.println("Consumer release LOCK_OBJECT lock");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2, new ThreadFactory() {
            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                int index = atomicInteger.incrementAndGet();
                System.out.println("create no " + index + " thread");
                Thread t = new Thread(r, "Thread-" + index);
                return t;
            }
        });
        TestSync ts = new TestSync();
        threadPool.execute(() -> {
            try {
                ts.doubleSync();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        Print.sleep(1000);
        threadPool.execute(() -> {
            try {
                ts.simpleSync();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        threadPool.shutdown();
    }
}

class Print {
    public static void sleep(long interval) {
        System.out.println("sleep " + interval);
    }
}
```

Note that it is recommended to call method `shutdown()`, of interface `ExecutorService`, after you have submitted all your tasks.

Here is the output when I run the above code.

```
create no 1 thread
Producer  trying to get LOCK_OBJECT lock 
Producer get LOCK_OBJECT lock 
sleep 1000
create no 2 thread
Consumer trying to get LOCK_OBJECT lock 
sleep 3000
full！
```

As you can see, the *consumer* does not obtain the lock.

Comment: yes,yes,Thank you very much for your correction. It was my oversight on the number of TestSync instances.

Answer (score 0):

> Does `wait()` release all locks?

No.  It only releases the lock for the object you call `wait()` on.

As for the behavior of your code ... we cannot fully explain it because it is missing a crucial method: `Print`.

However, it looks like you are using multiple instances of `TestSync`.  That would mean that the producer and consumer threads have different objects for the respective lock objects ... and there is no mutual exclusion.

---

It is also a bad idea (wasteful) to use multiple thread pools, and particularly to create and destroy them dynamically.  The primary advantage of thread pools compared with disposable threads is that the (significant) thread creation is amortized.  But when you shut down (or "lose") a thread pool, the threads get discarded anyway ... and have to be created again for the "next" thread pool.

(This doesn't affect the behavior of your example.  But it is a bad habit ... and it is liable to bite you if you do it in a real application.)

---

**Lesson:**  Programming with primitive mutexes and wait/notify requires considerable care.  It is better to use the higher level concurrency primitives ... where possible.

Answer (score 0):

1.It is always better to proceed with a one ExecutorService implementation (as we maintain limited number of thread alive all the time for performance reasons)

2.wait() does releases the lock for a single object but after that all the threads (considering same priority) are equally probable to get the lock